# Changing the values in txt file using R r

Tags: r, optimization, export, requirements.txt

I want to write a softcode that will change the values of required parameters of my Hydrological model input txt file. some parametres are fixed and some I will change to the observed values. For exampple HYDRUS_Version=4 is fixed and WaterFlow=1 and SoluteTransport=0 etc are the parametres that I want to change their values. I want to assign the values of waterFlow=5 or WaterFlow=3.1 and SoluteTransport=2 or =2.2

I tried this code for water Flow but the values in my txt files are not changed. I am just new learner of R.

```
    lines <- readLines("G:/Rlearning/HYDRUS1D.txt")

        library(gsubfn)
        i1 <- grepl("Vertical Conductivity", lines)
        lines[i1] <- gsubfn("[0-9.]+", ~format(as.numeric(x)*2, 
                                           scientific = FALSE), lines[i1])
```

Below is the complete txt file.

```
;
[Main]
HYDRUS_Version=4
WaterFlow=1
SoluteTransport=0
Unsatchem=0
Unsatchem=0
HP1=0
HeatTransport=0
EquilibriumAdsorption=1
MobileImmobile=0
RootWaterUptake=1
RootGrowth=0
MaterialNumbers=1
SubregionNumbers=1
SpaceUnit=cm
TimeUnit=days
PrintTimes=160
NumberOfSolutes=0
InitialCondition=1
;
[Profile]
NumberOfNodes=101
ProfileDepth=1.2E+02
ObservationNodes=5
GridVisible=1
SnapToGrid=1
ProfileWidth=80
LeftMargin=40
GridOrgX=0
GridOrgY=0
GridDX=5.E+00
GridDY=5.E+00
```

Comment: I was trying to just put the complete file as a normal writing but it accepted in code format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom function to search matching string and replace value:

```
replaceFn <- function(phrase, value, file){
  line <- file[grep(phrase, file)]
  value.pos <- as.numeric(gregexpr("=", line))
  file[grep(phrase, file)] <- paste0(substring(line, 1, value.pos), value)
  return(file)
}


dat <- replaceFn("WaterFlow", 3.1, dat)
dat <- replaceFn("SoluteTransport", 2.2, dat)

[1] ";"                       "[Main]"                  "HYDRUS_Version=4"        "WaterFlow=3.1"           "SoluteTransport=2.2"     "Unsatchem=0"            
[7] "Unsatchem=0"             "HP1=0"                   "HeatTransport=0"         "EquilibriumAdsorption=1" "MobileImmobile=0"        "RootWaterUptake=1"      
[13] "RootGrowth=0"            "MaterialNumbers=1"       "SubregionNumbers=1"      "SpaceUnit=cm"            "TimeUnit=days"           "PrintTimes=160"         
[19] "NumberOfSolutes=0"       "InitialCondition=1"      ";"                       "[Profile]"               "NumberOfNodes=101"       "ProfileDepth=1.2E+02"   
[25] "ObservationNodes=5"      "GridVisible=1"           "SnapToGrid=1"            "ProfileWidth=80"         "LeftMargin=40"           "GridOrgX=0"             
[31] "GridOrgY=0"              "GridDX=5.E+00"           "GridDY=5.E+00"
```

Input data:

```
dat <- c(";", "[Main]", "HYDRUS_Version=4", "WaterFlow=1", "SoluteTransport=0", 
"Unsatchem=0", "Unsatchem=0", "HP1=0", "HeatTransport=0", "EquilibriumAdsorption=1", 
"MobileImmobile=0", "RootWaterUptake=1", "RootGrowth=0", "MaterialNumbers=1", 
"SubregionNumbers=1", "SpaceUnit=cm", "TimeUnit=days", "PrintTimes=160", 
"NumberOfSolutes=0", "InitialCondition=1", ";", "[Profile]", 
"NumberOfNodes=101", "ProfileDepth=1.2E+02", "ObservationNodes=5", 
"GridVisible=1", "SnapToGrid=1", "ProfileWidth=80", "LeftMargin=40", 
"GridOrgX=0", "GridOrgY=0", "GridDX=5.E+00", "GridDY=5.E+00")
```

Comment: It is according to my question. Prof now assigned a new way. I will put another question. Thnx for writing this. It is good.  But now the issue is that we will not change the values here in the code manually, as you did. we have a text file where we have values of parameters. it will read the values from this txt file and assigned it here. Can you do that? I also did that with replace function. the code is on my lab computer. I will upload tomorrow. but he said we have WaterFlow value and all other parameters in the text file then it will read it. also, create that text file in R.

Comment: maybe my English is not good. dat <- replaceFn("WaterFlow", 3.1, dat) we can not do that in this way. it will read the value of 3.1 from a text file and this text file we will also create. thnx for the help.

Comment: Its my code, your and mine code need manual input. we need a soft code that will read the values of these variables from the an other text file. This text files have different rows and we just give him the command and it will read the specific row and assign the values from that rows. tx  <- gsub(pattern = "Unsatchem=1", replace = "Unsatchem=1", x = tx)
tx  <- gsub(pattern = "HP1=0", replace = "HP1=2", x = tx)
tx  <- gsub(pattern = "PrintTimes=170", replace = "PrintTimes=3000", x = tx)

writeLines(tx1, "G:/Rlearning/HYDRUS1D_1.txt")